# modify ion-datetime button css properties

Tags: css, ionic-framework, shadow-dom

I would like to change the button text-transform property of the datetime buttons to none. Right now my Buttons are looking like this:
[Buttons1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/32jz6.png)

According to the Ionic documentation I can not access button-properties via CSS shadow parts: https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/datetime#css-shadow-parts.

But according to the ion-button documentation, buttons can be reached via the native property:
https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/button#css-shadow-parts

So I have tried this here to access the buttons within the ion-datetime modal:

```
.export-ion-modal {
&::part(backdrop) {
    --backdrop-opacity: 0.3;
}
&::part(content) {
    background: var(--ion-color-primary-contrast);
    border-radius: 26px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px 5px rgb(0 0 0 / 32%);
}
&::part(native){
        text-transform: none;
}
}
```

Unfortunately, this did not work. Is it even possible to access the button properties of an ion-datetime somehow?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this my Js:

```
const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('ion-datetime ion-button');
buttons.forEach((button) => {
  button.style.textTransform = 'none';
});
```